# Can you simulate a GZK-energy cosmic ray zap to hardware you're simulating?

Tags: fpga, error, error-correction

There have been over a hundred particles of energy 5e19 eV matching the Greisen–Zatsepin–Kuzmin limit detected on Earth since 1991. There has even been a particle supposedly with energy at least 2e20.

So suppose I am simulating a CPU on an FPGA and sending instructions and receiving output from it all systematically. Now I want to simulate the "true analog" CPU operating and getting hit by such a cosmic ray. What would be the relevant parameters? A position, angle, and energy amount? I can pause at a clock tick and execute certain instructions, like "flip this register", or "disconnect that wire", but my issue is mainly that I don't actually understand what the range of effects that a cosmic ray of such an energy can actually affect a chip. Let's talk about slow old chips with little error correction if possible, I would name particular hardware but I like to keep the question general and copyright/trademark free.

The honest reason is that I would like to run brute force simulation of emulation of vintage hardware running a program of mine, with cosmic rays at "critical moments" of an application. So I have a point in the code I would like to say, "now, what if a cosmic ray hit at the time which maximizes chaos of the following instruction?" But what are the implications of one of these rays, or even multiple at a quick interval? Related would be whether or not these cosmic rays are ever found to be found in a quicker interval, but regardless, are there any papers discussing the potential effects of these things? It becomes worse in space with no atmosphere and so that's why I mean just 1 cosmic ray, or maybe 2-3 simulated but mostly just worrying about 1 or 2 in a 1us span let's say.

Comment: You'd need to simulate the device at a very detailed level; look at the virtual 6502 project to see the kind of detail your model would need to incorporate.

Comment: So A) no, not really. B) 10^19 eV is more than a joule, delivered in what, a microsecond? Just call the chip dead.

Comment: @hobbs its a single elementary particle, I don't know what the transfer does, or if it would go through the chip, etc. I need the answer, but I don't think it necessarily means the chip dies. If anything when the chip dies would be one of the less interesting cases.

Comment: @Snared you're not likely to find out without building a particle accelerator bigger than LHC. I suggest starting a Patreon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5e19 eV = 8 Joules according to an online calculator. To give you an idea of how much energy this is in a circuit 1/2C*V^2 gives you 6000V for a 1uF capacitor. Obviously a CPU doesn't have 1uF capacitors in it but just an idea.

If you could dump all that energy you could really develop a nice charge on something and bump all sorts of electrons out of the way.

One problem is all the energy would not be deposited in one spot, because as soon as the cosmic ray hits another particle, it causes a shower and the energy gets dispersed.

[image]
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_shower_(physics)

You could figure in a rough sketch of how much the residual particles (sometimes 5e10 particles by the time it reaches the ground). Averaging across particles (I am no physicist, and I'm sure some have more energy and some less) each particle would have about 1e9 eV of energy, which is 16 nano Joules. That is enough to charge a 1nF capacitor to 16V, which is still enough to wreck havoc on a CPU.

Needless to say, in your simulations, you could probably simulate various charges on capacitors and inject them into the processor to see if it is fault tolerant.